# What needs to be done to prove that a vector bundle is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology

What needs to be done to prove that a vector bundle is trivial? equivalently, This can be thought of as proving that the vector bundle satisfies the criteria of being trivial, then what is this criteria?

Comment: A vector bundle over $M$ is trivial when it is diffeomorphic to $M \times V$ for some vector space $V$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I do not have a counter-example on hand, but that is not the correct definition (and I believe that it is false that this implies the vector bundle $E$ is trivial): this diffeomorphism should also preserve the vector space structure on each fiber.

Comment: @MikeMiller - a less pompous reply would have been "you forgot to mention that the diffeomorphism must also be linear on each fiber."

Comment: To follow up on Mike's comment: We thought about nonisomorphic vector bundles with diffeomorphic total spaces a while ago. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943066/nonisomorphic-vector-bundles-with-diffeomorphic-total-spaces).

Comment: Don't forget that vector bundles don't necessarily have to have any kind of differentiable structure.

Answer (score 25):

Since the question of "How can you tell if a bundle is trivial?" is very general I wrote an expository essay answer, because there are a lot of interesting aspects to this problem and not a lot of computable, final answers. (After working on it a couple days I guess it's a bit long.)

Let $E\to X$ be a rank $n$ vector bundle over a sufficiently nice, connected space.

**Definition:** $E$ is *trivial* iff $E$ is vector bundle isomorphic to the trivial bundle $X\times \mathbb{R}^n$.

This is the definition of a trivial bundle with arbitrary fibre type, just with $\mathbb{R}^n$ plugged in and it has to be fibre-wise linear. Sometimes you get lucky and it's possible to just write down an isomorphism. I'll talk about 3 alternate approaches you could take to showing $E$ is trivial:

1. Find $n$ linearly independent sections.
2. Show a classifying map is null-homotopic.

2b) Compute characteristic classes.

Characteristic classes is "2b" because ultimately they are trying to compute wether a classifying map is null-homotopic or not (and sometimes succeed).

---

The fibre-wise linear structure of a vector bundle lets us prove the following criterion:

**Independent Sections:** $E$ is trivial iff it admits $n$ sections which are linearly independent at every point.

*Proof sketch:* A trivialization defines $n$ independent sections via the images of $X\times\{e_i\}$. Independent sections $\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\}$ define a basis for each fibre, inducing isomorphisms $E_x \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ which combine into a trivialization.

**Corollary (Real line bundles):** A one-dimensional real vector bundle is trivial iff it is orientable.

*Proof:* A non-zero section of a one-dimensional real vector bundle induces an orientation and vice-versa.

The problem of determining the maximum number of independent sections of a vector bundle is difficult, even when restricting to the problem of counting sections of a tangent bundle i.e. the so called **Vector Field Problem**. In some very nice cases the Euler Characteristic and the Signature can be used to detect a small number of independent vector fields (see e.g. [Atiyah-Dupont](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889716) or [Bökstedt-Dupont-Svane](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1007.215&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), but detecting if the tangent bundle is completely trivial is much harder and the obstructions don't admit such a convenient interpretation.

However, in the extra-special case that a smooth manifold has a smooth group structure then it is paralellizable:

**Lie groups:** The tangent bundle of a Lie group is trivial.

*Proof sketch:* Choose a frame in the tangent space at the identity, and then use the derivative of left-translation to transport it to any other tangent space.

---

Another way to express the triviality of a bundle is via **classifying spaces**: for any topological group $G$ there is a *classifying space* $BG$ and a *universal principal $G$-bundle* $EG\to BG$ such that principal $G$-bundles (and by extension bundles with structure group $G$) are classified by maps to $BG$. More specifically for any $X$ there is a natural bijection

$$[X, BG] \cong Prin_G(X)$$

where $[-,-]$ is the set of (pointed) homotopy classes of maps, $Prin_G(-)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles; the bijection sends a map $c\colon X \to BG$ to the bundle $c^*EG$.

In the case of vector bundles the structure group is $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, and as long as $X$ is paracompact we can even chose a metric and reduce it to $O(n)$ or $U(n)$. Then the classification theory gives us the following criterion:

**Null-homotopic Classifying Map:** Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $X$, classified by a map $c\colon X\to BO(n)$ (or $BU(n)$). Then $E$ is trivial iff $c$ is null-homotopic.

*Proof sketch:* This is because the pullback of a bundle along a constant map is trivial, and because of the homotopy invariance property of bundles: if $f,g\colon X \to Y$ are continuous and $E\to Y$ is any fibre bundle, then $f\sim g \implies f^*E\cong g^*E$.

**Corollary (Contractible Base Space):** Suppose $X$ is contractible. Then any vector bundle over $X$ is trivial.

It's usually not easy to tell when a map is null-homotopic, short of actually writing down a homotopy.

You could trying showing that the induced map on homotopy groups is $0$ and then try to conclude that the map is null-homotopic, but this is not always the case, even for CW complexes: Chris Schommer-Pries points out in an answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20275/maps-inducing-zero-on-homotopy-groups-but-are-not-null-homotopic) that a map of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces $K(\mathbb{Z}/2, i) \to K(\mathbb{Z}/2, i+1)$ inducing a Bockstein homomorphism is certainly $0$ on homotopy groups, but there are spaces with non-zero Bocksteins and so this map cannot be null-homotopic.

If $X$ is a CW complex you can try to use Obstruction Theory to try to compute the obstructions to a null-homotopy and show they all vanish. This approach *usually* doesn't work unless the obstruction groups all vanish, but here they typically will not (the coefficients are of the form $\pi_rBO(n)$ which is often non-zero).

---

A coarser way of trying to detect if a bundle is trivial is via **characteristic classes**: given a classifying map $f\colon X \to BG$ and a cohomology theory $h$ we can study the map $f^*\colon h^*(BG) \to h^*(X)$, and in particular try to determine weather it is the $0$ map or not. If $f^* \neq 0$ then $f$ is not null-homotopic, but the converse isn't necessarily true. In fact there is a rather deep sub-question to your question, which is

> "When do characteristic classes determine the isomorphism type of a vector bundle?"

In the classical case $G=O(n), SO(n),$ or $U(n)$, and $h=H^*(-;R)$ for some $R$. The classical characteristic classes are the polynomial generators of $H^*(BO(n);\mathbb{Z}/2)$ (the Stiefel-Whitney classes), $H^*(BO(n);\mathbb{Z})/torsion$ (Pontryagin classes), and $H^*(BU(n);\mathbb{Z})$ (Chern classes). These classes are all **stable**, in the sense that they are invariants of the bundle's *stable* isomorphism class, and therefore vanish for a bundle which is stably trivial. There is also an *unstable* Euler class in $H^{n}(BSO(n);\mathbb{Z})$, whose square is $0$ if $n$ is odd and $p_{\frac{n}{2}}$ if $n$ is even. (See Milnor-Stasheff for way more information.)

**Characteristic Classes Sometimes Work:** The simplest case of them sometimes working is $1$-dimensional bundles. Observe that $O(1)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ so  $BO(1)\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)$, and $U(1)\cong SO(2) \cong S^1$ so $BU(1)\simeq BSO(2)\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ so they represent cohomology groups. Namely

$$ [X, BO(1)] \cong H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2) $$
$$ [X, BU(1)] \cong [X, BSO(2)] \cong H^2(X;\mathbb{Z}) $$

and in fact

**One-dimensional Bundles:** Let $E$ be a one dimensional vector bundle. If it is real then it is trivial iff $w_1(E)=0$; if it is complex then it is trivial iff $c_1(E) = 0$

**Oriented plane bundles:** Let $E$ be an oriented rank-two bundle. Then $E$ is trivial iff $e(E) = 0$.

There are several other low-dimensional cases that have been resolved where characteristic classes determine bundle type, but not as cleanly or generally, such as [Cadek](https://eudml.org/doc/31374) and others I'm forgetting right now.

There are also some technical conditions that you can require of two spaces $X$, $Y$ so that singular cohomology can detect maps $f\colon X\to Y$ that are not null-homotopic (see for example [Sternstein](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2037939?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)), so if your $X$ and $BG$ do happen to satisfy these criteria then characteristic classes will determine bundle type. (There are other papers along these lines but I can't seem to find them right now, hopefully people can add some references in the comments.) For example if $X$ and $BU(n)$ satisfy the criteria then a bundle classified by $c$ will be trivial iff $H^*(c)=0$, iff all the Chern classes vanish.

**Sometimes They Don't:** There are many [examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112764/non-stably-trivial-bundle-with-trivial-characteristic-classes) of bundles whose classical characteristic classes (Stiefel-Whitney, Pontryagin, Chern) vanish but which are NOT trivial, sometimes not even *stably* trivial.

If you're in a situation where classical characteristic classes do not determine bundle type, there are a few things you could try:

If your bundle's structure group can be reduced further then sometimes there are new characteristic classes which provide new information. For example, the tangent bundle $TS^n$ is stably trivial and so all of its $O(n)$ characteristic classes vanish, but by giving it the standard orientation it gets a classification map to $BSO(n)$ and the Euler class gets pulled back to $2 \in H^{2k}(S^{2k};\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, so an $SO(n)$ characteristic class DOES detect the non-triviality of $TS^{2k}$. (I don't know if it's possible in general to always reduce to a structure group with a characteristic class that detects your bundle.)

In come contexts *secondary characteristic classes* can be defined when primary characteristic classes vanish. This is not something I'm very familiar with, but it's a thing.

You could do something more drastic like change your cohomology theory. As well as $H^*(-;R)$ people also care about $K$-theory and bordism characteristic classes, but the computations are typically much more difficult. But, with the increased richness there's also a higher chance it could detect the non-triviality of your classifying map. There is a caveat though: if a map $f\colon X \to Y$ is stably null-homotopic (in the sense of stable homotopy theory, not bundle stabilization) then $f^*\colon h^*(Y) \to h^*(X)$ will be $0$ for any cohomology theory and so cohomology would be unable to determine if $f$ is null-homotopic. On the other hand, if $f$ is *not* stably null-homotopic and $h_Y$ is the cohomology theory defined by $\Sigma^{\infty}Y$ then $f^*\colon h_Y^*(Y)\to h_Y^*(X)$ is also not $0$, but the cohomology groups $h_{BG}^*(X)$ can be very daunting.

---

I think that's about all I can come up with on this problem. I definitely left out of a lot stuff and there's definitely stuff I don't know so hopefully people can add things in the comments or with more answers.