# Are all vector bundles of the form $E=X\times V$ trivial?

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

This might be a silly question, but bear with me.

Let $X$ be a topological space, $V$ a vector space and consider the vector bundle $E=X\times V$ with $\pi:E\to X$, $(p,v)\mapsto p$. This is the trivial $V$-bundle over $X$.

I had been under the impression that any vector bundle $E'=X\times V$ was trivial, but I realised that I had not been accounting for the fact that for a trivial bundle, $\pi$ must be projection onto the first factor. My question is, can we show that $E\cong E'$ in general, even when $\pi':E'\to X$ is not just projection onto the first factor?

To show this, I would need to find a homeomorphism $\phi:E\to E'$ such $\pi'\circ\phi=\pi$, and $\pi'=\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$. The obvious idea would be to use the local trivialisations of $E'$, but I don't quite see how to do so.

Any help or references would be much appreciated.

Comment: In [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58802/21564), Igor Belegradek gives an example of a non-trivial rank two bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ whose total space is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Oh fantastic, thank you! I had somehow missed that MO question. If you upgrade your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the answer to the question is no, as demonstrated by the following example by Igor Belegradek in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58802/21564) which I have replicated below:

> Consider the pullback $\xi$ of $TS^2$ via the projection of $S^2\times\mathbb R$ onto the first factor. The bundle $\xi$ is a nontrivial $\mathbb R^2$-bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb R$ because its pullback under the inclusion $S^2\to S^2\times\mathbb R$ is $TS^2$, which is nontrivial. On the other hand, its total space is $\mathbb R\times TS^2$ which is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\mathbb R^3$, which is the total space of the trivial $\mathbb R^2$-bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb R$.

Let me add some details.

Let $\pi : TS^2 \to S^2$ be the vector bundle projection, and $\operatorname{pr}_1 : S^2\times\mathbb{R} \to S^2$ the natural projection map. Define $\xi := \operatorname{pr}_1^*TS^2$ and consider the inclusion $i : S^2 \to S^2\times\mathbb{R}$, $p \mapsto (p, 0)$. Note that

$$i^*\xi = i^*\operatorname{pr}_1^*TS^2 = (\operatorname{pr}_1\circ\ i)^*TS^2 = \operatorname{id}_{S^2}^*TS^2 = TS^2.$$

As the pullback of a trivial bundle is trivial, and $i^*\xi = TS^2$ is non-trivial, we see that $\xi$ is a non-trivial vector bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle#Formal_definition), the total space of $\xi$ is given by

$$\xi = \operatorname{pr}_1^*TS^2 = \{((p, t), v) \in (S^2\times\mathbb{R})\times TS^2 \mid \pi(v) = p\}.$$

Now note that, as bundles over $S^2$, we also have

$$\varepsilon^1\oplus TS^2 = (S^2\times\mathbb{R})\oplus TS^2 = \{((p, t), v) \in (S^2\times\mathbb{R})\times TS^2 \mid \pi(v) = p\}$$

where the last equality is the [definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum+of+vector+bundles#definition) of the direct sum of vector bundles.

As $TS^2 \to S^2$ is stably trivial, $\varepsilon^1\oplus TS^2 \cong \varepsilon^3 = S^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$. So the total space of the non-trivial rank two vector bundle $\xi \to S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence to the trivial rank two vector bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $(S^2\times\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^2$.

The point is that the total space of the non-trivial vector bundle $\xi \to S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ can also be viewed as the total space of a trivial bundle over $S^2$.

Comment: That's a very nice example.  It seems to me that all one needs to make it work is that $TS^2$ is both non-trivial and stably trivial.  In particular, it should work for $TS^{2n}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: You are correct. In general, if $E \to B$ is a continuous/smooth real rank $m$ vector bundle such that $E\oplus\varepsilon^n \cong \varepsilon^{m+n}$, then the total space of the corresponding bundle $\xi$ is homeomorphic/diffeomorphic to the trivial rank $m$ real vector bundle over $B\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I see.   Do you happen to know of an example of a non-stably trivial bundle $E\rightarrow B$ where $E$ is abstractly diffeomorphic to $B\times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I don't. If you assume that the diffeomorphism $E \to B\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is compatible with the projections to $B$, then all the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $E$ vanish.

Comment: To make sure I understand your last comment, the point is that you're *not* assuming that the diffeo acts linearly on each fiber, right?  I'm guessing a proof:  Thom has a defintion of SW via the Thom isomorphism and Steenrod powers on the Thom space of a vector bundle.  it seems like such a diffeo induces a homeo of the Thom spaces.  If this line of reasoning works, I think it also works merely having a homeomorphism $E\rightarrow B\times \mathbb{R}$ compatible with the projections.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Right, I'm not assuming the diffeomorphism is linear on each fiber. That's not the proof I had in mind. Instead $w(TE) = \pi^*w(TB)\pi^*w(E)$ while $w(T(B\times\mathbb{R}^n)) = \operatorname{pr}_1^*w(TB)$. The diffeomorphism $\varphi : E \to B\times\mathbb{R}^n$ being compatible with the projections means $\operatorname{pr}_1\circ\varphi = \pi$, so $\varphi^*w(T(B\times\mathbb{R}^n)) = \pi^*w(TB)$.

Comment: Makes sense!  Thanks